# Does $ M$ which is diffeomorphic to torus have vanishing $K$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, curvature

Consider a closed manifold $M $ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Assume $M$ is diffeomorphic to a torus. Then I want to know is it possible to have $K(p)=0$ for every point $p\in M$? Here $K$ is Gaussian curvature.

First what I know, is diffeomorphic does not guarantee the Gaussian curvature of $M$ and Gaussian curvature of the torus are the same. How one can prove or disprove such a statement?

Comment: Remember that any compact $C^2$ surface (so that curvature makes sense) in $\Bbb R^3$ must have a point of positive curvature. Look at spheres emanating from a fixed point and look at the sphere of minimal radius so that the surface is contained inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A smooth isometric embedding ($C^\infty$) of the flat torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not possible, but according to the Nash-embedding-theorem it is possible to have a $C^1$ map. See this [Math overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31222/c1-isometric-embedding-of-flat-torus-into-mathbbr3) .

Comment: Note that you need a $C^2$ (or close to it) submanifold for curvature even to make sense.